# How shall I deal with the repositories with different status in the output of apt update?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management

In the output of `apt update` running on Lubuntu 18.04, what does the first word in each line mean? They can be `Hit, Get, Ign, Err, E, N`, and `W`. Which values of the first word deserve attention to deal with, and how?

I think my repository information is a mess, and I would like to learn about how to clean it up.

Thanks.

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                       
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                                                     
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:5 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                          
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                                                      
Ign:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                     
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/adrozdoff/emacs/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                           
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                                                                                                   
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable Release                                                                                                       
Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                                      
Hit:12 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                 
Hit:13 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease                                                                                                        
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                 
Hit:15 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                               
Hit:16 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                 
Hit:17 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/mssql-server-2019 bionic InRelease                                                                                            
Ign:18 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:19 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease                                                                                                         
Hit:20 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 Release                                                                                                        
Hit:21 https://xpra.org bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Ign:22 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease                                            
Err:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/adrozdoff/emacs/ubuntu bionic Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:24 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release [815 B]
Get:25 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease [3,626 B]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [897 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [661 kB]
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [310 kB]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [307 kB]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [73.8 kB]         
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [140 kB]     
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [37.5 kB]  
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted Translation-en [9,524 B]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [1,011 kB]
Get:38 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [677 kB]                               
Get:40 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [454 kB]                                                                                             
Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,060 kB]                                                                                     
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [218 kB]                                                                                            
Get:43 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [38.5 kB]                                                                                    
Get:44 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [17.6 kB]                                                                                       
Get:45 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [41.5 kB]                                                                                       
Get:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted amd64 Packages [28.5 kB]                                                                                     
Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted Translation-en [7,568 B]                                                                                     
Get:48 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [653 kB]                                                                                        
Get:49 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [328 kB]                                                                                       
Get:50 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [617 kB]                                                                                         
Get:51 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [273 kB]                                                                                
Get:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [213 kB]                                                                                   
Get:53 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [217 kB]                                                                                        
Get:54 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [497 kB]                                                                                   
Get:55 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [42.1 kB]                                                                                
Get:56 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16.4 kB]                                                                                   
Get:57 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [116 kB]                                                                                    
Get:58 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]                                                                              
Get:59 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]                                                                             
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,980 B]                                                                             
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                    
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/adrozdoff/emacs/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:1
```

The custom part in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
deb [arch=armhf,amd64,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/mssql-server-2019 bionic main
# deb-src [arch=armhf,amd64,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/mssql-server-2019 bionic main
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/
```

and

```
$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
adrozdoff-ubuntu-emacs-bionic.list       google-chrome.list.save    msprod.list             ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-audacity-bionic.list       xpra.list.save
adrozdoff-ubuntu-emacs-bionic.list.save  microsoft-prod.list        mysql.list              ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-audacity-bionic.list.save
chrome-remote-desktop.list               microsoft-prod.list.save   sbt.list                vscode.list
chrome-remote-desktop.list.save          mongodb-org-4.0.list       skype-stable.list       vscode.list.save
google-chrome.list                       mongodb-org-4.0.list.save  skype-stable.list.save  xpra.list
```

Answer (score 3):

"Hit" means apt checked the timestamps on package list, those match and there are no changes.

"Ign" means there are no changes in the pdiff index file; it won't bother downloading it again.

"Get" means apt checked the timestamps on package list, there were changes and will be downloaded.

"Err" means some error occured with that repo.

In your case the repo in  **Err** is unreachable.
Remove that repo, then update and you won't get errors.

Comment: Thanks. What do "E", "N" and "W" in the beginning of lines in the output of `apt update` mean?

Comment: @Tim I believe those stand for "error," "notice," and "warning."